# Finding the number of checked check-boxes in a form gives double the actual count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to count the number of contact check-boxes checked/selected in a form.
What could be wrong with the below code snippet which actually gives double the count.

HTML:

```
<div ng-hide ="onOff">
<span class="ctCheckBox" ng-class="{'searchDataCheckbox':searchView}">
<label class="atl-check-box-label">
<input type="checkbox" class="atl-check-box" ng-checked="iscontactChecked(info.userId)" ng-click ="grpAct()">
<span class="fntIcons appFtIcns"></span>
</label>
</span>
</div>
<div ng-hide ="!onOff">
<span class="ctCheckBox" ng-class="{'searchDataCheckbox':searchView}">
<label class="atl-check-box-label">
<input type="checkbox" class="atl-check-box" ng-checked="iscontactChecked(info.userId)" ng-click ="grpAct()">
<span class="fntIcons appFtIcns"></span>
</label>
</span>
</div>
```

The HTML form is a huge one and it has both `<span class="ctCheckBox" ..` and `<input type="checkbox" class="atl-check-box" ..` in other places too. However, only the above HTML code is displayed on the application view.

JS:

```
$scope.selectedContactsCount = angular.element('.ctCheckBox input:checked').length;
alert('1st alert: ' +$('input:checkbox:checked').length);
alert('2nd alert: ' +$('.atl-check-box input:checked').length);
```

All of the above 3 JS statements yield the wrong number of selected check-boxes:

1. 1st one gives double the actual selected check box count
2. For 2nd, count is 27
3. For 3rd, count is 0

Ex: If the only 2 contacts which are being displayed on the application view are being selected, then 4 is shown as the count of the number of selected contacts, if 3 contacts are selected, then 6 is shown as the count of the number of selected contacts and so on.

Am I missing something?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Then you have more elements matching the selector than you think you have. The second example shouldn't return anything?

Comment: @adeneo, thanks for the quick response. I have edited my question to mention that HTML form is having these check-boxes with same span and input checkbox class names in other places too, but on the application view, only these many are displayed.

Comment: Corrected the 2nd JS statement in my above query. How do I find out the more elements matching the selector and rectify the count to show the proper value?

Comment: If there are more elements matching the selector, you have to make the selector more specific, for instance by adding an ID to the parent span

Comment: @NathanBarkan can you provide a simple example like a JSFiddle, with the data provided it will be hard to find the issue!, for now you can do `console.log($('input:checkbox:checked'))` and check what elements are actually getting selected in the HTML inside the console window`, it must be as adeneo suggested!

Comment: @adeneo, @Naren Murali

We are using 2 blocks in our HTML:
`ng-hide ="onOff"` and 
`ng-hide ="!onOff"`,
both of which contain the same above HTML snippet posted in the query. Could this be the reason why all checked checkboxes are repeating twice and hence the count is doubling as `angular.element('.ctCheckBox input:checked').length;` is counting all the elements rendered on the DOM whether hidden or displayed? I have edited my query to include this part.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my problem. The real reason why the count was getting doubled was due to the usage of `ng-hide`, instead of `ng-if`, which would show the selected contacts in the DOM in spite of being hidden or displayed and resulting in `angular.element('.ctCheckBox input:checked').length` finding 2 occurrences (a duplicate) of the same checkbox.
`ng-if` has solved this problem now as checkboxes get rendered conditionally on DOM, however, there is some other change in the application's initial loading of the list of contacts behaviour which will be looked into.